# automating filing out pdfs with iText and java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm looking to automate filling out a pdf contract by putting variable text in predefined locations(such as a date or dollar value). I've been trying to wrap my head around iText as a solution but am having trouble actually stamping text onto a pdf. I would really appreciate an example snipped that simply stamps a piece of text on a specific (x,y) coordinate of a pdf file.

If there is a better solution than iText to my problem I would also love to hear other possible solutions.

Comment: What about http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=3 or better: http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=6 (§6.3.1)

Comment: @RC If I use the pdfcontentbyte example, http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=26, it seems to delete all other content on my pdf is that normal and how do I stop that? I'm trying to use the site you linked but I don't own the book so I'm working blindly through the examples.

Comment: The [HelloWorldDirect](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=26) you refer to creates a new PDF. Thus, obviously, any file at the give location before is lost, and so are its contents.